# Editing Wordpress theme to have less padding on sides

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog at [www.cattywampur.com](http://www.cattywampur.com)

I really like the free theme I am using, I just want the content part to be a bit wider. There is a lot of padding to the left of the blog post writing and to the right of the right side bar.

Looking in inspect element I do not see any padding values. I see a width value for content but if I increase it, it makes the right sidebar disappear like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `.post-inner` is the class you're going to want. If you wish to remove "padding" from the post area you could add something like the following to `style.css` in your child-theme:

```
.post-inner {
    max-width: 90%;
    width: 700px
}
```

If you'd like to increase the post width you'll have to also decrease the width of the sidebar, otherwise the sidebar will clear the post content and end up on the bottom of the page. Something like the following ought to do the trick.

```
.content {
    width: 76%;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 22%;
}
```

Use the two blocks of CSS in conjunction in order to achieve an effect like this!
[image: cattywampur post width increase]
**Note:** I've also added `padding: 30px 0;` to `.post-inner` in order to even things out.

Comment: Your answer helped get me in the right direction. What I really wanted to do was increase the text area, which I have done. I am now trying to figure out how to kind of center it all. You can see the updates live on the site www.cattywampur.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change (or add) attributes to class **post-inner** ( .wrapper section .section-inner .content .posts .post .post-inner )

```
.post-inner {
    max-width: *your value - i suggest use %*;
    width: *your value*;
}
```